# Calculating jumping distance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, biophysics, biology

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the jumping distance of a person or animal based on body weight and initial speed, but I can't seem to find any relevant information online about this. Is there any formula that can be used to figure this out?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion. If you know the initial speed & the angle at which the animal jumps, you can calculate how far it goes. Body weight does not affect the results.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a physics question - certainly a biophysics question - and not off-topic here at all.

Comment: No response? Do you disagree with my answer or do you need something clarifying?

Answer (score 0):

Flees, grasshoppers and frogs are amongst the champions in jumping distance in terms of their own body lengths and these type of creatures generally jump from a standing start with zero initial horizontal velocity as they do not have time to get a running start before jumping to get away from a predator. I am going to disregard this group and only consider jumping distance in absolute horizontal distance terms. This is highly dependent on morphology and a quick survey of the animal kingdom tends to suggest that heavier animals with more muscle mass and longer legs such as humans and antelopes have the advantage over smaller animals such as rabbits, but body mass is not everything and heavier animals such as hippos and elephants are generally considered poor jumpers.

To try and quantify things it is probably best to compare jumping ability within a limited group such as a group of competing humans with similar morphologies.

The equation for the distance travelled by a projectile over flat ground is $$ d = \frac{v^2}{g} \sin (2 \ \theta) ,$$  where $\theta$ is the launch angle relative to the ground, v is the initial take off velocity with both horizontal and vertical components and g is the acceleration of gravity. The horizontal component of the velocity $v_x$ can be assumed to be the horizontal velocity of the run up just prior to the jump and the vertical component of the velocity $v_y$ is produced by the impulse produced by the leg muscles pushing up off the ground at the last second.

Since the resultant velocity v is given by $v = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}$ we can replace the $v^2$ term in the expression with $(v_x^2 + +v_y^2)$ and get $$ d = \frac{(v_x^2 +v_y^2)}{g} \sin (2 \ \theta) $$  and since $\theta = arctan(v_y/v_x)$ we can substitute this and obtain  $$ d = \frac{(v_x^2 + v_y^2)}{g} \sin (2 \ arctan(v_y/v_x)) $$

We can reformulate $v_y$ in terms of the impulse (I) generated by the legs pushing up off the ground at the last second and the mass (m) of the human so that $v_y = I/m$ and substitute this expression into the previous equation to obtain $$ d = \frac{(v_x^2 + (I/m)^2)}{g} \sin \left(2 \ arctan\left(\frac{I}{m v_x}\right)\right) $$

A plot of this function reveals that the distance is inversely related to the mass and increases as the ratio $I/m$ increases and mass does affect the distance negatively. This is because for a given vertical force, a larger body mass reduces the vertical $v_y$ component of the take off velocity which in turn reduces the resultant total take off velocity.

Since it is well known that projectile range is maximised when the take off angle is 45 degrees, it would seem reasonable to assume that $v_x$ should be kept close to $v_y$ [but a plot reveals that the jump distance increases linearly with $v_x$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Plot%20%5C%2840%29Power%5Bv%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B5%2C100%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29*Divide%5B1%2C9%5C%2844%298%5D*sin%5C%2840%292*arctan%5C%2840%29Divide%5B5%2C100*v%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%20from%20v%3D1%20to%20v%20%3D100) for a given fixed $v_y$. In fact, doubling either $v-x$ or $v_y$ doubles the jump distance.